# How to decided the score threshold in speaker recognition?

Tags: algorithms, speech-processing, audio-processing, machine-learning, speech-recognition

I am new to speaker recognition and now starting from the **GMM-UBM** algorithm.

Say I have a pre-trained `UBM` and speech from target speakers `tarsph` to derive target speaker model `tarmod`. And I could get a **loglikelihood ratio** `LLR` as score of speech from unknow speakers `uksph` by pesudo code below:

```
LLR = get_LLR(uksph, tarmod, UBM);
```

I think there should be **a (set of) threshold** of `LLR` to decide if `uksph` **is/isn't** from one of the target speakers. But how to decide the threshold(s)?

The classical way comes to my mind is to **partition** the `tarsph` to **adaptation** and **validation** set, the former is used to derive target speaker model, and the latter could be used to get some value of `LLR`s. Then we can use average(or other statistics) of these as a **empirically threshold**. It could be better to have speech from non-target speaker from which we can know the risk of false alarm.

What I am wondering is:

1. Is my concept about GMM-UBM algorithm right or there is some **misunderstanding**?
2. Is there a **standard/most commonly used method** to decide the `LLR` threshold?
3. In a practical situation, it is possible to get **less speech data**(maybe only **a few seconds** per target speaker) than an experimental corpus. Will this be a problem to this algorithm?

Comment: For selection of the score threshold you can use [DET Curves](https://ccc.inaoep.mx/~villasen/bib/martin97det.pdf) or standard ROC curves. For Detection Error Tradeoff curve you can also use the EER (Equal-Error-Rate) as a point where FN and FP rate is equal.
Alternatively, for multiple classifiers, you can calibrate your scores (e.g. using isotonic regression) so that the threshold is optimal.

Comment: @jojek
Hi, thank you for your suggestion.
These days I have spent some time on [DET Curves](https://ccc.inaoep.mx/~villasen/bib/martin97det.pdf), [SV tutorial](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1155/S1110865704310024.pdf) and [Score Normalization](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S1051200499903603). It seems that still have to collect some data, scoring on it with speaker models, then to derive DET or ROC curve to choose an operating point(=choose the score threshold).

Comment: As I'm going to implement this algorithm on a low-level end-device(like Cortex-M0), procedure above will take a long time to computing, is there any solution for reducing the computing time?

Also, is score-normalization necessary if a set of speaker-specific/dependent threshold is acceptable?